# Testing error case with observables in services

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-coverage, angular2-testing, angular2-observables

Let's say I have a component that subscribes to a service function:

```
export class Component {

   ...

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.doStuff().subscribe(
            (data: IData) => {
              doThings(data);
            },
            (error: Error) => console.error(error)
        );
    };
};
```

The subscribe call takes two anonymous functions as parameters, I've managed to set up a working unit test for the data function but Karma won't accept coverage for the error one.

[image]

I've tried spying on the console.error function, throwing an error and then expecting the spy to have been called but that doesn't quite do it.

My unit test:

```
spyOn(console,'error').and.callThrough();

serviceStub = {
        doStuff: jasmine.createSpy('doStuff').and.returnValue(Observable.of(data)),
    };

    serviceStub.doStuff.and.returnValue(Observable.throw(

        'error!'
    ));

serviceStub.doStuff().subscribe(

    (res) => {

        *working test, can access res*
    },
    (error) => {

      console.error(error);
      console.log(error);  //Prints 'error!' so throw works.
      expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith('error!'); //Is true but won't be accepted for coverage.
    }
);
```

What's the best practice for testing anonymous functions such as these? What's the bare minimum to secure test coverage?

Comment: Your test makes no sense; you're replacing the callback you say you want to test. Just testing that `subscribe` calls its second argument when an error occurs isn't testing your code, it's testing the framework, which is an anti pattern. Also you provide two different outcomes for your mock call on consecutive lines.

Comment: Okay, so what would be a good way of testing it? Throwing an error in a separate it-block?

Comment: You need to call the actual implementation, but you haven't shown enough of a [mcve] to guess how that could be achieved.

Comment: any update for this question?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can simply mock Observable throw error object like `Observable.throw({status: 404})`and test error block of observable.

```js
const xService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(SomeService);
const mockCall = spyOn(xService, 'method').and.returnValue(Observable.throw({status: 404}));
```

Update 2019 :

Since some people are lazy to read comment let me put this here :
It's a best practice to use errors for Rxjs

```js
import { throwError } from 'rxjs'; // make sure to import the throwError from rxjs
const xService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(SomeService);
const mockCall = spyOn(xService,'method').and.returnValue(throwError({status: 404}));
```

**Update 2022:**
Use of `throwError` in the aforementioned way is deprecated. Instead, use `throwError(() => new Error({status: 404}))`:

```js
import { throwError } from 'rxjs'; // make sure to import the throwError from rxjs
const xService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(SomeService);
const mockCall = spyOn(xService,'method').and.returnValue(throwError(() => new Error({status: 404})));
```

Comment: Use `import { throwError } from 'rxjs'` and then `returnValue(throwError({status: 404}));` for rxjs >= v6.

Comment: @Aniruddha, how can I return an error object instead of a string? I need to return `{ error: { message: 'Error' }}`

Comment: When I throw the error, the tests start failing, even tho the throwing the error is intentional

Answer (score 21):

Not sure exactly the purpose of the code you are showing, which is trying to test a mock service. The coverage problem is with the component and the error callback to not have been called (which is only called when there is an error).

What I usually do for most of my observable services, is to create a mock whose methods just returns itself. The mock service has a `subscribe` method that accepts the `next`, `error`, and `complete` callbacks. The user of the mock gets to configure it to add an error so the `error` function gets called, or add data, so the `next` method gets called. The thing I like most about this is that it's all synchronous.

Below is something like what I normally use. It's just an abstract class for other mocks to extend. It provides the basic functionality that an observable provides. The extending mock service should just add the methods it needs, returning itself in the method.

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

export abstract class AbstractMockObservableService {
  protected _subscription: Subscription;
  protected _fakeContent: any;
  protected _fakeError: any;

  set error(err) {
    this._fakeError = err;
  }

  set content(data) {
    this._fakeContent = data;
  }

  get subscription(): Subscription {
    return this._subscription;
  }

  subscribe(next: Function, error?: Function, complete?: Function): Subscription {
    this._subscription = new Subscription();
    spyOn(this._subscription, 'unsubscribe');

    if (next && this._fakeContent && !this._fakeError) {
      next(this._fakeContent);
    }
    if (error && this._fakeError) {
      error(this._fakeError);
    }
    if (complete) {
      complete();
    }
    return this._subscription;
  }
}
```

Now in your tests you just do something like

```
class MockService extends AbstractMockObservableService {
  doStuff() {
    return this;
  }
}

let mockService;
beforeEach(() => {
  mockService = new MockService();
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [{provide: SomeService, useValue: mockService }],
    declarations: [ TestComponent ]
  });
});
it('should call service success', () => {
  mockService.content = 'some content';
  let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
  // test component for success case
});
it('should call service error', () => {
  mockService.error = 'Some error';
  let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
  // test component for error case
  // this should handle your coverage problem
});

// this assumes you have unsubscribed from the subscription in your
// component, which you should always do in the ngOnDestroy of the component
it('should unsubscribe when component destroyed', () => {
  let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.destroy();
  expect(mockService.subscription.unsubscribe).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had mocked the fake error response in service.ts

By commenting previous http call and

let error:any = new Error("failed");
return new Observable(error);

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2022**

Since `of()` seems to be deprecated, I'm using it like this:

```
jest.spyOn(service, 'query').mockReturnValue(throwError(() => new Error("a error message")));
```

Comment: `of()` is not depricated