# Why am I getting a "Failed: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined" while running tests?

Tags: angular, observable, karma-jasmine

I am relatively new to testing in Angular2+ and am setting up my files for testing. Since building the project, I've written a lot of code and am now trying to test parts of it. However, lots of those tests are now broken so I am now trying to delete the unneeded default tests or fix the ones that are useful.

This particular test won't run because it fails before it hits the It() testing method. I'm not sure what I'm missing, any help would be appreciated.

I am receiving this error:

```
Failed: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at AppComponent../src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.setupLanguageTranslation (src/app/app.component.ts:48:26)
    at AppComponent../src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.ngOnInit (src/app/app.component.ts:32:14)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:22089:1)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:23353:1)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:23315:1)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:23949:1)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:23909:1)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:9:9)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:23901:1)
    at checkAndUpdateView (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:23297:1)
```

I've tried a variety of articles with similar issues including, but not limited to:

- [Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined after running npm test (Angular 2 unit testing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142300/cannot-read-property-subscribe-of-undefined-after-running-npm-test-angular-2)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/87w8su/what_am_im_doing_wrong_with_observables_and/
- [karma TypeError "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942482/karma-typeerror-cannot-read-property-subscribe-of-undefined?rq=1)

App.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    title = 'planox';
    showError = false;
    errorMessage = '';
    translatedText: string;

    constructor(private _translate: TranslateService,
                private utils: Utils) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.setupLanguageTranslation();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this._translate.onLangChanged.unsubscribe();
    }

    setupLanguageTranslation() {
        this.subscribeToLangChanged();
        // set language
        this._translate.setDefaultLang('en'); // set English as default
        this._translate.enableFallback(true); // enable fallback

        // set current language
        this.selectLang('en');

        this.utils.error.subscribe(response => {
            this.errorMessage = response;
            this.showError = true;
            setTimeout( () => {
                this.showError = false;
            }, 2000);
        });
    }

    selectLang(lang: string) {
        // set default;
        this._translate.use(lang);
    }

    subscribeToLangChanged() {
        // refresh text
        this.refreshText();
        return this._translate.onLangChanged.value;
    }

    refreshText() {
        // refresh translation when language change
        this.translatedText = this._translate.instant('hello world');
    }

}
```

app.component.spec.ts

```
import {TestBed, async, ComponentFixture, inject} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {TranslateService} from './translate/translate.service';
import Utils from './shared/utils';
import {MockTranslateService} from './mocks/mockTranslateService';
import {MockUtils} from './mocks/mockUtils';
import {TRANSLATIONS} from './translate/translation';


describe('AppComponent', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        const mockTranslate = new MockTranslateService(TRANSLATIONS);
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule
            ],
            declarations: [
                AppComponent
            ],
            providers: [
                {provide: TranslateService, useValue: mockTranslate},
                {provide: Utils, useValue: MockUtils},
            ]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        fixture.detectChanges();
    }));

    it('should create the app', () => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
        expect(app).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Utils.ts:

```
import {Subject, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Role} from '../classes/role/role.enum';

export enum KEY_CODE {
    ENTER = 13,
    RIGHT_ARROW = 39,
    LEFT_ARROW = 37
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export default class Utils {
    error: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    handleError(service: string, error: Response | any, customMessage?: string) {
        const err = service + '::handleError' + '=  ' + error;
        this.error.next(customMessage);
        return throwError(error);
    }

    encodeBase64(value: any) {
        return btoa(JSON.stringify(value));
    }

    decodeBase64(value: any) {
        return atob(value);
    }

    navigateToDefaultPage(usersRole: Role) {
        if (usersRole === Role.Employee) {
            this.router.navigate(['/dashboardNavigation', {outlets: {dashNav: ['productionDashboard']}}]);
        } else if (usersRole === Role.Client) {
            this.router.navigate(['/clientDashboard']);
        } else if (usersRole === Role.OfficeAdmin) {
            this.router.navigate(['/dashboardNavigation', {outlets: {dashNav: ['enterpriseDashboard']}}]);
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
        }
    }

    validateEmail(inputText: string) {
        const mailFormat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        if (inputText.match(mailFormat)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

mockUtils.ts

```
import Utils from "../shared/utils";
import {Subject} from "rxjs";

export class MockUtils extends Utils {
    error = new Subject<string>();
}
```

Basically I need help setting up the structure of the testing page so that I can start writing useful tests.

I can provide any additional code you may need to help, wasn't sure what all would be needed for this.

Comment: can you add `MockUtils` definition.

Comment: @LostJon it's just a wrapper right now with nothing in it, was a pattern I saw in https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/overview/. Should I try overriding the failing variable in there?

Comment: Thats your problem then....Utils initializes with `error: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();` so your mock error needs to do the same

Comment: @LostJon so I just added that and I'm still getting the same error. Added the file above as well.

Comment: seeing MockUtils now, you dont need to add that error in there since its extending `Utils`...the only other debugging i can offer is to `console.log(this)` and `console.log(this.utils)` before you do the subscribe call to make sure they are populated the way you intend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

delete **fixture.detectChanges()** from  the beforeEach method, remove it from there, and moving it  into each test if needed will fix it for you, i think it's a bug, seen it on Angular 6 and Angular 7

so your beforeEach will change to:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    const mockTranslate = new MockTranslateService(TRANSLATIONS);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            RouterTestingModule
        ],
        declarations: [
            AppComponent
        ],
        providers: [
            {provide: TranslateService, useValue: mockTranslate},
            {provide: Utils, useValue: MockUtils},
        ]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    // detection deleted here
}));
```

Comment: I was struggling with the same error, surprisingly this solved it. Thanks!

Comment: My project is using Angular 8.3 and this still worked for me. Thank you for saving my sanity. Still feels more like a workaround than an actual fix.