# Cant understand the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, integration-testing

I have written an implementation to obtain data from API calls. However, while testing the functionality I am getting the following errors even before writing any meaningful test cases:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at DataComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/dashboard/job/job.component.ts:48:10)
    at callHook (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:3405:1)
    at callHooks (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:3375:1)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:3327:1)
    at refreshView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:8573:1)
    at renderComponentOrTemplate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:8672:1)
    at tickRootContext (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:9885:1)
    at detectChangesInRootView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:9910:1)
    at RootViewRef.detectChanges (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:10320:1)
    at ComponentFixture._tick (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/testing.js:243:1)
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing, any help would be appreciated.
I looked into the following to get some understanding:

- [Why am I getting a "Failed: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined" while running tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958449/why-am-i-getting-a-failed-cannot-read-property-subscribe-of-undefined-while)   -> the solution did not work in my case
- [karma TypeError "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942482/karma-typeerror-cannot-read-property-subscribe-of-undefined?rq=1)

and some other references.

Here are my code files. I have removed certain parts of my code that I felt were not relevant to the issue at hand.

dataService.ts code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IData } from '../model/data.model';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import {catchError, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getData(): Observable<IData[]>{
    return this.http.get<IData[]>('url')
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('Data Received')),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse){
   //handle error code
  }
}
```

component I am testing -> data.component.ts code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { IData } from '../../model/data.model';
import {DataService} from '../../service/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-job',
  templateUrl: './job.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./job.component.css']
})
export class JobComponent implements OnInit {

   @Input() appId: string;

   jobs: IData[] = [];
   
   constructor(   private dataService: DataService ) {}

   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.dataService.getData().subscribe({
         next: data => {
            this.data = data;
         },
         error: err => this.errorMessage = err
      });
   }
//other implementation
}
```

Testing file :  data.spec.ts:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DataComponent } from './job.component';
import { IData } from 'src/app/model/job.model';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/service/job-data.service';
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

describe('DataComponent', () => {
  let component: DataComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DataComponent>;
  let mockDataService ;
  let JOBS: IData[];
  

  beforeEach(async () => {
    mockJobDataService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getData']);
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DataComponent ],
      providers: [
        {provide: DataService, useValue: mockDataService}
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents()
    .then(() => {
      DATA = [{id: 'CJH'}];
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DataComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();  //updates bindings
    });
  });

  it('should return true',() => {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
  })
  
});
```

When I remove `fixture.detectChanges()`, the error gets removed. But in my understanding the test cases should work even if I use this call anywhere in my test.

Comment: Apologies for a mistake. For the purpose of posting the issue, I changed the names for components and variables, but missed a few places. Replace all occurances of 'job' to 'data'. (like JobComponent->DataComponent, JOBS->DATA etc)

Comment: why don't you define a 'getData' fake implementation for your 'mockDataService' mock value ?

Comment: @habibchabbi Do you mean this?

mockDataService=  {
      getData: () => {return of(DATA);}
    }

Comment: yes doesn't this work ?

Comment: yes, its working now. I made a silly mistake earlier. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome !

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a spy object with `mockJobDataService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getData']);` and are registering it correctly with this `{provide: DataService, useValue: mockDataService}`. At this point, your component should get created correctly with your fake service injected into it. The problem is that you aren't setting up the expected method call on your fake service.

Something like the following should do the trick as long as you do it before you call `fixture.detectChanges()`. Since you don't include the shape of the `IJob` interface, I can't tell you exactly, but I have made it work with typescript through casting it(`({} as IJob)`).

`import { of } from 'rxjs';`

`mockJobDataService.getData.and.returnValue(of([({} as IJob)]));`

This tells jasmine that anything using this fake data service, upon calling the getData method, the return from that method should be `of([({} as IJob)])`(this is an observable of type IJob array).

As you move forward and write tests that actually are testing your component, you will probably want to move the mocked method and the 'detectChanges' call into each test so that you can provide different fake data for every test.