# How to simulate the failure of mock service in karma?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, angular, typescript, karma-runner

Obeservable function in example.component.ts

```
public name: string;

this._cm.getData().subscribe(
    response => {
       this.name = response.name;
    },
    error => {
        this.name = undefined;
    }
```

Mock service

```
public _cm = {
    data: {
        name: 'test'
    }

    getData(): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.of(this.data);
    }
}
```

Test observable function in example.component.spec.ts

```
// this test work corectly
it('Should set name property to "test"', () => {
    comp._cm.getData();
    expect(comp.name).toBe('test');  
}

it('Should set name property to undefined', () => {
    comp._cm.getData();
    expect(comp.name).toBe('undefined');  
}
```

but I do not know how to simulate error response getData()

Answer (score 2):

You should just create the `Observable` using `Observable.create`. With this, you can control when the error should be emitted. For example

```
public _cm = {
    error: false,
    data: {
        name: 'test'
    },
    getData(): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            if (this.error) {
                observer.error(new Error("Boo"));
            } else {
                observer.next(this.data);
            }
            observer.complete();
        })
    }
}
```

Now you can just control the error in your test

```
_cm.error = true;
// do test
```

**See Also:**

- [Angular 2 - Testing error case with observables in services](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39960878/2587435)

Comment: Method works, but I had to change:
    observer.onError to  observer.error
    observer.onNext to observer.next
    observer.onComplete to observer.complete